# Russian characters instead of French or German, with Helvetica font

Tags: fonts

I was having problems with websites requiring the Helvetica family-font in their css: all special french and german characters were replaced by unrelated russian characters.

That put me on the track of Helvetica. I have launched `font-manager`, to check about Helvetica. And when I enter custom text, the font is simply wrong.

Example text:

```
être, spécial, déjà, aïe, bücher, öffentlich,  währe
```

Visual result:

[image: font-manager display]

How could I fix the Helvetica font so as it displays properly ?

Edit:

`locate Helvetica` returns:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/psprint/fontmetric/Helvetica-Bold.afm
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/psprint/fontmetric/Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/psprint/fontmetric/Helvetica-Oblique.afm
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/psprint/fontmetric/Helvetica.afm
/usr/share/fonts/downloaded_unknown_copyright_use/Helvetica.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathematica/Helvetica-Bold.afm
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathematica/Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathematica/Helvetica-Oblique.afm
/usr/share/fonts/type1/mathematica/Helvetica.afm
/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts/Helvetica-Bold.afm
/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts/Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm
/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts/Helvetica-Oblique.afm
/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts/Helvetica.afm
/usr/share/perl5/Font/Metrics/Helvetica.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Font/Metrics/HelveticaBold.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Font/Metrics/HelveticaBoldOblique.pm
/usr/share/perl5/Font/Metrics/HelveticaOblique.pm
```

Comment: In what application(s) do you have this problem?

Comment: @Gilles in `font-manager`, `firefox`, and `chromium-browser`

Comment: Obviously I have downloaded Helvetica somewhere I don't even know of... `/usr/share/fonts/downloaded_unknown_copyright_use/Helvetica.ttf` I should probably try to find a more serious source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `Helvetica.ttf` had unknown origins.

I have deleted this file and everything is back in order now.

It is also possible to install a free variant of *Helvetica* that can be found here:  [Helvetica Neue](http://downloadfontsfree.net/fonts/13035/helvetica_neue_lt_std.html), it works ok.